# Check if CIDR block is contained within another range in Terraform

Tags: terraform

How can one check if CIDR block or IP is contained within a CIDR range in Terraform?

Does a function like `contains_cidr(block1, block2)` exist that would return a boolean if `block2` was contained within `block1`?

```
contains_cidr("10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.0.1/32") => TRUE
contains_cidr("10.0.0.0/24", "10.1.1.1/32") => FALSE
```

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Most recent time I've wanted something like this was for creating the smallest set of CIDR blocks for a route table. Imagine I have both 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.0.1/32 in a list of CIDR ranges to add to a route, I can limit it to just 10.0.0.0/24 which would be neater.

Comment: But the longest prefix match would apply anyway. So the /32 route would be used probably.

Comment: I believe the /24 would be used at least in AWS vpc route tables. But what if you just want things nice and neat and no other reason. Can't we all yearn for cleanliness?

Comment: Sure. Terraform is open source, so if a functionality is missing, you can try to contribute. :)

Comment: That might indeed be the way! Figured I'd check to see if it was possible first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such build in functionality. But you can easily add it to your TF through [custom data sources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). You would have to write some script in bash/python or whatever, that would do the check for you, and return the outcome to your TF code for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin [`cidrhost()`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/cidrhost) function in an arguably wasteful way, this can be achieved. There is a caveat though.

```
variable "subnet" {
  default = "10.0.0.42/32"
}
variable "supernet" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/24"
}
locals {
  super_prefix_len = tonumber(split("/", var.supernet)[1])
  super_host_len = 32 - local.super_prefix_len
  super_host_count = pow(2, local.super_host_len)
  super_all_addrs = [for i in range(0, local.super_host_count) : cidrhost(var.supernet, i)]
  first_address_contained = contains(local.super_all_addrs, cidrhost(var.subnet, 0))
  last_address_contained = contains(local.super_all_addrs, cidrhost(var.subnet, -1))
  result = local.first_address_contained && local.last_address_contained
}
output "result" {
  value = <<EOT
  ${var.subnet} is${ local.result ? "" : " not"} in ${var.supernet}"
  First address ${cidrhost(var.subnet, 0)}, last address ${cidrhost(var.subnet, -1)}
EOT
}
```

This works by building a tuple or list of all the IP addresses contained in the CIDR range to check against. Depending on the size of the CIDR range, this could be millions of entries but terraform imposes an artificial limit of 1024 entries on the `range()` function to prevent excessive memory usage (Who on earth would waste resources like this I wonder?).

This limitation means this solution is only useful up to /22 networks.

Results:

```
$ terraform plan 

Changes to Outputs:
  + result = <<-EOT
        10.0.0.42/32 is in 10.0.0.0/24"
          First address 10.0.0.42, last address 10.0.0.42
    EOT

$ terraform plan -var "subnet=10.1.1.1/32"

Changes to Outputs:
  + result = <<-EOT
        10.1.1.1/32 is not in 10.0.0.0/24"
          First address 10.1.1.1, last address 10.1.1.1
    EOT

$ terraform plan -var "subnet=10.0.0.0/16"

Changes to Outputs:
  + result = <<-EOT
        10.0.0.0/16 is not in 10.0.0.0/24"
          First address 10.0.0.0, last address 10.0.255.255
    EOT

$ terraform plan -var "subnet=10.0.0.0/16" -var "supernet=10.0.0.0/8"

Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on main.tf line 11, in locals:
│   11:   super_all_addrs = [for i in range(0, local.super_host_count) : cidrhost(var.supernet, i)]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling range(params...)
│     │ local.super_host_count is 16777216
│ 
│ Call to function "range" failed: more than 1024 values were generated; either decrease the difference between start and end or use a smaller step.
╵
```

---

There may be ways around the limitation of `range()` along the lines of

```
locals {
  long_range = flatten([for i in range(0,1024): range(i* 1024, i * 1024 + 1024)])
}
```

Trying this got the terraform process to almost half a gig of memory used and took 80s to execute on an M1 MacBook Pro. This would still only get us to a /20, so the real world usefulness of it seems dubious.

### Updated solution converting dotted decimal subnet strings to numbers

```
# Returns boolean value indicating if a subnet is inside another network (supernet)
variable "supernet" {}
variable "subnet" {}

locals {
  addresses = {
    super_first = cidrhost(var.supernet, 0)
    super_last  = cidrhost(var.supernet, -1)
    sub_first   = cidrhost(var.subnet, 0)
    sub_last    = cidrhost(var.subnet, -1)
  }
  octets = { for name, address in local.addresses : name => split(".", address) }
  int_addresses = {for name, address in local.octets : name =>
    address[0] * 256 * 256 * 256 +
    address[1] * 256 * 256 +
    address[2] * 256 +
    address[3]
  }
  is_supernet = local.int_addresses.sub_first >= local.int_addresses.super_first && local.int_addresses.sub_last <= local.int_addresses.super_last
}

output "result" {
  value = local.is_supernet
}
```

Can be used as a module:

```
module "subnet_in_primary_cidr" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.vpc.ids)
  source   = "./isinsubnet"

  subnet   = data.aws_subnet.vpc[each.value].cidr_block
  supernet = data.aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block
}
```

Comment: The way better approach would of course be to convert the edges of the ranges to integers. Then just check that the lowest address of the supernet is lower or equal than the first one of the subnet and >= for the highest.